# Tombstoning in Caliburn Micro

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro, tombstoning

I have MainPageViewModel with Items (ObservableCollection). On this page I also have a button, that add new items to Items.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : Screen {
  private DateTime StartActivity = DateTime.MinValue;

  public ObservableCollection<ActivityViewModel> Items { get; set; }

  public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) {
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ActivityViewModel>();
  }

  public void AddActivity(string activityName) {
    if (this.Items.Count == 0) {
      this.Items.Add(new ActivityViewModel() { 
        Activity = activityName, 
        Duration = 0 
      });

      StartActivity = DateTime.Now;
      }
    else {
      this.Items[this.Items.Count - 1].Duration = 10;
      this.Items.Add(new ActivityViewModel() { 
        Activity = activityName,
        Duration = 0 
      });

      StartActivity = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
}
```

Adding new items works perfect.

But data from Items not recovers when app activates after tombstoning. Try create StorageHandler for my ViewModel. Doesn't help. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainPageViewModelStorage : StorageHandler<MainPageViewModel> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Property(x => x.Items)
        .InAppSettings()
        .RestoreAfterActivation();
  }
}
```

Also try add [SurviveTombstone] for class and for property but Visual Studio don't know that attribute.

```
public class ActivityViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {
  private string _activity;
  public string Activity {
    get {
      return _activity;
    }
    set {
      if (value != _activity) {
        _activity = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Activity);
      }
    }
  }

  private double _duration;
  public double Duration {
    get {
      return _duration;
    }
    set {
      if (value != _duration) {
        _duration = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Duration);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should store not `InAppSettings` but `InPhoneState`.
2. Check with breakpoint if method `Configure` is called. If not - something wrong with your bootstrapper. Probably `PhoneContainer.RegisterPhoneServices()` is missing
3. Turn on catching first chance exception in Visual Studio (Ctrl+Alt+E, and put checkbox against CLR Exceptions). Probably your view model cannot be deserialized properly.